# How do I create a 1 byte file in JAVA to store binary values (eg:10100011)?

Tags: java

1 byte = 8 bits, how can I create and store `11001100` in those 8 bits 
and the file should be 1 byte in size?

What should be the file format?

All this in Java.

Comment: a) You've added quite a few tags. Do you need all of them? JavaScript ≠ Java. b) What have you tried?

Comment: I want to store in the format-

Comment: 1st byte-11001100, 2nd byte-10100100 so as to compress the file size instead of a .txt file which will be in KBs .

Answer (score 0):

To write bytes to a file, you can use `FileOutputStream`.

See: [Lesson: Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials and see the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.bin")) {
            out.write(0b11001100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How  do i again get back the data from the .bin file?

Comment: Use a `FileInputStream` to read it back. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Comment: what if we have to the value as String s="11001100";

Comment: how will we pass value in s in to the .bin file

Comment: @ASHWINNAYAK if it's in a string, parse it first: `out.write(Integer.parseInt(s, 2));`

Comment: Sir, how to get number of rows in a MySql database, using jdbc.

Comment: @ASHWINNAYAK That is a completely different question, ask it separately instead of putting it in a comment here.

Comment: ok sir,, what if i have an integer array of 8 values, how to convert it into a byte?

Comment: @ASHWINNAYAK you can use a [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to go over the array and use [bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) to set the appropriate bits in the byte.

Comment: If the binary value is 2 byte long like 1001000010001000 then it is showing error, any solution sir?

Comment: i mean a string that has String s= 1001000010001000; its too large .so showing error

Comment: @ASHWINNAYAK then you'll have to use another type instead of `byte` to store the value; use `int`, for example.

Comment: public class Labrat6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String byte1="10101010";
      String byte2="1010101011111111";
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.bin")) {
            out.write(11000000);
            out.write(Integer.parseInt(byte2,2));
       }
    }
}

Comment: when i store values with 2 byte or 16 bit size,, in the .bin file.  Its only takes the second byte.

Comment: for example if input is 1010101011111111 then it stores only FF that is 11111111

Comment: @ASHWINNAYAK please ask this in a separate question instead of trying to post code and discuss in comments.